# PHP4 problems with include() within a file created by fwrite()

Tags: php, permissions, include, php4, fwrite

I have a file called `generator.php` that uses `fwrite()` to create a `result.php` on the server (Apache, PHP4).

One of the lines in `result.php` is a PHP `include()` statement.

So, in `generator.php`:

```
if (!is_file($fname)){
    $resultfile = fopen($current_path . "/" . $fname, "w+");
}
fwrite($resultfile, '<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "'. '/inc/footer.php"); ?>' . "\n");
fclose($resultfile);
chmod($current_path . "/" . $fname, 0755);
```

And in `result.php`:

```
<h2>Sponsored Links</h2>
<!-- begin sidebar_top ad -->
<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ads/sidebar_top.php" . "<hr />";
  include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ads/sidebar_top.php"); ?>
<!-- end sidebar_top ad -->
```

But that `include()` statement doesn't work when I visit `result.php` in a browser. The echo statement does, so I know the path is correct.

Another `test.php` with the same code, which I uploaded using FTP into the same folder, works fine.

The code in the same in both files, when recovered via FTP.

In `test.php`: (works, echoes and includes correctly.)

```
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ads/sidebar_top.php" . "<hr />";
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/ads/sidebar_top.php"); 
?>
```

Any idea why the `include()` is working in `test.php` (created manually) and not in `result.php` (created using `fwrite()`), when both are in the same folder?

The only differences I know of between the files:

1. Owner could be different (wouldn't `result.php` be created by user `nobody`?)
2. Permissions are originally different. FTP'd file (working) is `0775`, while    the ones created using fwrite() (include not working) had `664`, and is chmoded by the `generator.php` to `0775`.
3. Working `test.php` file was edited on a Mac with Smultron and uploaded via FTP, while `result.php` was created by `fwrite()` in `generator.php` on Linux, called from a browser.

Comment: Is the file closed before being executed? Also, can we see both generated files?

Comment: Have you tried downloading result.php with an FTP browser and manually checking that they are identical? Also, do you get any errors when you visit result.php (either on the page or in the log)?

Comment: Yes make sure you're calling fclose($fp) before trying to execute it.  Also ftp the output file and manually check the contents.

Comment: Yes, the result.php file is executed much later, manually (via a browser). The contents seem to be same when checked via FTP.

Comment: I actually snipped 2 lines of the code from the result.php (by getting it through FTP) and created test.php..

Also, if I replace 'include' by 'require' then it just stops at that sentence.

Comment: Have added more code to the question. The code in the file that works looks exactly the same as the file that doesn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When PHP4 safe mode is on, the `result.php`, being written by another uid, cannot not access the included file, which belongs to another uid.

> SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 48 is not allowed to access
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/ads/sidebar_top.php owned by uid 10010
>   in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/results/result.php on line 130

I resolved this by opening `php.ini` and changing to `safe_mode_gid = On`, and adding my includes directory to `safe_mode_include_dir`.

I also had to restart Apache to let the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
fwrite($resultfile, '<?php include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/inc/footer.php"); ?>' . "\n");
```

you had an extra " in there i think

Comment: It's a superfluous concatenation, but I think it's not relevant to the issue.